# Android : Restore time in resume

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have question i have a chronometer in my app, when i back to my main window, and get back to Timer activity, I just want to resume a time on chronometer from CountDownTimer, how to to this ? Bundle doesn't help me and similar topics :( I will be very gratefull for any help.

```
public class Timer extends Activity {
    private boolean start = false; // Semafor to button
    private Chronometer timer; // Chronometr
    private CountDownTimer count; // CountDown class
    private final long startTime = 30 * 1000; // High 
    private final long end = 1 * 1000; //LOw
    private ImageButton startB; // Button
    private int VIBRATION_TIME = 1000; //vibration time 
    private Bundle state = new Bundle(); //button state
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
        this.timer = ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1)); 
        count = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, end); 
        timer.setText("00:" + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000)); 
        startB = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.start_pause); 

        startB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_button);
        startB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // click init
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                start = !start;
                if (start == true) {
                    count.start(); // start count
                    startB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop_button);
                } else {
                    count.cancel(); // pause count

                    startB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_button);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ....
   @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        start = state.getBoolean("Button");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        state.putBoolean("Button", start);
        //count.cancel(); I don't wanna this!
    }


    class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("00:00");
            // TO DO :

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(VIBRATION_TIME);
            startB.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start_button);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long tmp = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                timer.setText("00:" + tmp);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make use of `onSaveInstanceState`. Override this method, and save your current time into the Bundle. Then, on `onCreate`, extract the value from the Bundle and apply it to your View.

Comment: onCreate and in onResume; and you can get the savedBundle in onRestoreInstanceState, Override These Method to get saved Data on Bundle when User come back to your app

Comment: As long as the activity doesn't get closed

Comment: Oww Thanks for answer that's very simple :) Thank's a lot I will try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm yes that is correct what Alex says but I have new idea. CountDownTimer start count, we click backButton activity is killed, but CountDownTimer still counting, but when I use this activity again, I can run new timer and this is crazy, there is any way to do this like that : In create method we check that CountDownTimer is still running and we just update a chronometer, but if not we create everything from new? At now my solutions is tricky: override the onBackPressed() and add this moveTaskToBack(true); but this not back to my mainActivity but return to telephone screen.